# Order by LastModified MediaStore.Audio List and set height row

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, mediastore

I am developing Android Application, where show .mp3 audio list of device. I use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Gallery"), 2);
```

Result:
[image: List of audio on device]

This working but my issue is that I need show this ordered by time (created or last modified) and other issue is that It have 3 lines but this is wrong, the 3rd line is not see.

Thanks.